# Why is luminous intensity dependent on the incident angle?

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics

Why is luminous intensity dependent on the incident angle which hits a surface of a specific area?

Answer (score 3):

Because luminus intensity (a.k.a. irradiance) is power per unit area (e.g. w/mm^2), and if the light rays are at an angle to the surface area over which you want to know the irradiance, then you have to project this area in the direction of the light rays - hence the you usually multiply by cos(alpha), where alpha is the angle between the light rays and the normal to the surface.